# Is meteor unstable on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, meteor

I have had basic tests for meteor on a Windows7 PC.
But there the application crashed too often.
Before this, I tested meteor on PC running Windows8. There, crashes happened much less often and generally they were recovered when I shutdown and rebooted the meteor.

Is Meteor unstable on windows7?
Or is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: What version of Meteor Windows do you use?

Comment: *Meteor PREVIEW 0.6.4* Maybe you should lower your expectations...

Answer (score 1):

The version packaged to the MSI installer that can be found on win.meteor.com is not official. If you want a more stable, try the virtualized option I've described on the site. I've been using that for a month without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you be specific about what problems you are seeing, for example, what do you mean by 'crash'.
You can certainly raise issues on SO, but if they appear to be specific to the windows port, please raise a ticket at: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor

The only difference between Win7 and Win8 meteor, is that the installer sets the Win7 compatibility mode for the node.exe executable on Windows 8.

There are also relatively few differences between the windows port of meteor and the official linux/mac release. So there is a possibility that the issue is either environmental (e.g. you have different things installed on the two machines), or it may even be a core issue that just happens to appear more often Win7 due to timing issues (there was a case of this in 0.6.3).